# Batch File: Output of IF and ELSE Statements Are Reversed Within Menu Script

Tags: networking, command-line, batch, remote, wmic

**THE PROBLEM**: *When the If (goto) statement equals "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional", it's going to the else statement, not the if statement.* When the first goto statement is chosen, the second goto statement is executed.

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic /Node: "pc-%cn%" os get caption') do @echo.%%x
if "%%x"=="Microsoft Windows 7 Professional" (goto seven) else (goto ten)
```

I am running this on remote computers (thereby the /Node inclusion).

Here is the entire Batch File:

```
@ECHO OFF


:: +++++++++++++++++ ENTER PC +++++++++++++++++++
cls
echo.
echo PC Tasks
echo --------
echo.
set /p "cn=Enter Computer Name Extension: "


:: +++++++++++++++++++ MENU +++++++++++++++++++++
:begin
cls
echo.
echo 1) OS Build Version
echo 2) Exit
echo.
goto option

:option
set /p op=Type option #:
if "%op%"=="1" goto test
if "%op%"=="2" goto exit


:: ++++++++++++++++++++ OPTIONS ++++++++++++++++++++++

:test
:: Check for OS
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic /Node: "pc-%cn%" os get caption') do @echo.%%x
if "%%x"=="Microsoft Windows 7 Professional" (goto seven) else (goto ten) 
echo.
pause
goto option

:seven
:: Windows 7 Build Version
systeminfo /s pc-%cn% | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
echo.
goto option

:ten
:: Windows 10 Build Version
psexec \\pc-%cn% cmd.exe /c Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ReleaseId
echo.
goto option

:exit
@exit
```

Thank you to anyone who is able to help.

Comment: Try splitting the if else across multiple lines. See [If - Conditionally perform command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: **DavidPostill** Thanks so much for that website. It is a great resource. But splitting the if else across multiple lines did not work.

Comment: **DavidPostill** Thanks again. Your answer got me closer to the full solution..."splitting the if else across multiple lines". This was the first part. The other part was what Namelessone came up with...to remove the quotes from Microsoft Windows 7 Professional. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work with the following syntax. I removed the quotation marks around Microsoft Windows 7 Professional. And additionally split IF/ELSE across multiple lines.

```
if "%%x"==Microsoft Windows 7 Professional (
goto seven
) else (
goto ten
)
```

Comment: **Namelessone** Thanks so much. That worked perfectly